# Simple Wordpress question

Tags: wordpress

I've been programming for like 5 straight hours and my brain has kinda stopped functioning.

I can't remember how to do this:

There is a page called Blog on my website, and I need to show all posts from my blog on that page. The Blog page is using custom template... Therefore, it's not index.php...

Please help me, I'm lost :/

Answer (score 0):

Include loop.php in your template. That is what gets and displays posts.

Answer (score 0):

To show blog post on a custom markup template, you can use this procedure, to loop if there are any posts and print them via the_content function.

```
<?php
  if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      the_content();
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```